# Set disable property for TableView individual cells

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, tableview, tablecell

How to set disabled property for individual cells in TableView?

Here is my scenario: one column has a `ComboBoxTableCell`, and depending upon which item is selected, some cells on the same row will be disabled.

For example:

[image: disable Input A or B depending on Type]

if I choose Type A, then Input A is enabled and Input B is disabled, and vice-versa.

By disabled I mean cleared, grayed out and not editable.

A minimal example of my scenario:

**TableTest.java**

```
package minimalexample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application {

    private TableView itemsTable;

    ObservableList<ItemsTableLine> items;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.addAll(new ItemsTableLine("A","1","2"),
                     new ItemsTableLine("A","3","4"),
                     new ItemsTableLine("B","5", "6"),
                     new ItemsTableLine());

        ItemsTable itemsTableParent = new ItemsTable();
        itemsTable = itemsTableParent.makeTable(items);

        VBox root = new VBox();        
        root.getChildren().addAll(itemsTable);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Minimal Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**ItemsTable.java**

```
package minimalexample;


import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class ItemsTable {

    private String lastKey = null;

    // This will be exposed through a getter to be updated from list in LoadsTable
    private TableColumn<ItemsTableLine, ItemType> typeCol;
    private TableColumn<ItemsTableLine, String> inputACol;
    private TableColumn<ItemsTableLine, String> inputBCol;

    public TableView makeTable(ObservableList<ItemsTableLine> items) {

        TableView tv = new TableView(items);
        tv.setEditable(true);

        Callback<TableColumn<ItemsTableLine, String>, TableCell<ItemsTableLine, String>> txtCellFactory
                = (TableColumn<ItemsTableLine, String> p) -> {
                    return new EditingCell();
                };

        ObservableList<ItemType> itemTypeList
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ItemType.values());
        typeCol = new TableColumn<>("Type");
        inputACol  = new TableColumn<>("Input A");
        inputBCol   = new TableColumn<>("Input B");

        typeCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ItemsTableLine, ItemType>, ObservableValue<ItemType>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<ItemType> call(CellDataFeatures<ItemsTableLine, ItemType> param) {
                ItemsTableLine lineItem = param.getValue();
                String itemTypeCode = lineItem.typeProperty().get();
                ItemType itemType = ItemType.getByCode(itemTypeCode);
                return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(itemType);
            }
        });

        inputACol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("inputA"));
        inputBCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("inputB"));
        typeCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(itemTypeList));
        inputACol.setCellFactory(txtCellFactory);
        inputBCol.setCellFactory(txtCellFactory);
        typeCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<ItemsTableLine, ItemType> event) -> {
            TablePosition<ItemsTableLine, ItemType> pos = event.getTablePosition();
            ItemType newItemType = event.getNewValue();
            int row = pos.getRow();
            ItemsTableLine lineItem = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
            lineItem.setType(newItemType.getCode());
        });
        inputACol.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ItemsTableLine, String> evt) -> {
            evt.getTableView().getItems().get(evt.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    .inputAProperty().setValue(evt.getNewValue().replace(",", "."));
        });
        inputBCol.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ItemsTableLine, String> evt) -> {
            evt.getTableView().getItems().get(evt.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    .inputBProperty().setValue(evt.getNewValue().replace(",", "."));
        });


        tv.getColumns().setAll(typeCol, inputACol, inputBCol);

        return tv;
    }

    private class EditingCell extends TableCell {
        private TextField textField;
        @Override public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                //setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY); 
                Platform.runLater(() -> {//without this space erases text, f2 doesn't
                    textField.requestFocus();//also selects
                });
                if (lastKey != null) {
                    textField.setText(lastKey);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {textField.deselect(); textField.end();});}
            }
        }
        public void commit() { commitEdit(textField.getText()); }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            try {
                setText(getItem().toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
                if (!getTableColumn().getText().equals("Name")) {
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                }
            }
        }
        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
                    (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) -> {
                        if (!arg2) { commitEdit(textField.getText()); }});
            textField.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent t) -> {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    EditingCell.this.getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell(); }
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) { cancelEdit(); }});
            textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent t) -> { 
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) { t.consume();}});
        }
        private String getString() {return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();}
    }
}
```

**ItemsTableLine.java**

```
package minimalexample;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class ItemsTableLine implements Serializable {

    private StringProperty type;
    private StringProperty inputA;
    private StringProperty inputB;

    public StringProperty typeProperty() {return type;}
    public StringProperty inputAProperty()  {return inputA;  }
    public StringProperty inputBProperty()   {return inputB;}

    public ItemsTableLine() {
        super();
        type = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        inputA  = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        inputB   = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    }

    public ItemsTableLine(String...values) {
        this();
        type.set(values[0]);
        inputA.set(values[1]);
        inputB.set(values[2]);
    }

    // Setters required due to combobox 
    public void setType(String value) {
        type.set(value);
    }
}
```

**ItemsType.java**

```
package minimalexample;

public enum ItemType {
    TYPEA("A", "Type A"),
    TYPEB("B", "Type B");
    private String code;
    private String text;
    private ItemType(String code, String text) { this.code = code; this.text = text;}
    public String getCode() { return code; }
    public String getText() { return text; }
    public static ItemType getByCode(String genderCode) {
       for (ItemType g : ItemType.values()) if (g.code.equals(genderCode)) return g;
       return null;
    }
    @Override public String toString() { return this.text; }
}
```

Comment: a bit on the not-so minimal side ;) Wondering why your model exposes the type as String (vs. as ItemType)? With the latter, you could get rid of edit handlers, simply use the properties in valueFactories. Also, you would need to make the items fire when the type changes by using a observableList with an extractor. And in the cells for the other columns, check the type and en/disable as needed.

Comment: difficult to have minimal and working examples in Java =) No particular reason why the model is exposing Strings, rather than my limited skills in java and javafx. If you could make an answer with your proposal so that I could accept it.

Comment: as I said: on the not-so minimal side ;) please throw out the custom editing cell and edit handlers (the former is not needed due to having TextFieldTableCell, the latter is not needed if the model is set up correctly)

Comment: actually, this looks like a modeling problem: it should be the model (or a view wrapper) that defines when a cell should be enabled, not the cell itself (which should be as simple as possible, having no responsibility about the logic, just a slave that follows its master). From a model perspective, it feels wrong that inputA can be !=null for typeB ...

Comment: hmm ... there might be an issue in core, can't make it work with a quick check .. need to dig a bit later this week .. sry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needs some refactoring but you can achieve what you are asking for by doing the following:

```java
inputACol.setCellFactory(param -> new EditingCell() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null && !empty) {
            ItemsTableLine data = (ItemsTableLine) getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
                    !data.typeProperty().get().equals("A"), data.typeProperty()));
        } else {
            disableProperty().unbind();
        }
    }
});
inputBCol.setCellFactory(param -> new EditingCell() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null && !empty) {
            ItemsTableLine data = (ItemsTableLine) getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
                    !data.typeProperty().get().equals("B"), data.typeProperty()));
        } else {
            disableProperty().unbind();
        }
    }
});
```

**Note**: There is more than one way of doing that, but this seems to be the easiest in your case.

**Note**: Both code blocks are identical except for the value used in the binding, you can write a method that takes that as an input and returns a cell factory instead of code repeating.